# Injecting HTML into a page using Mechanize

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, mechanize

I am writing a webscraping program to get my grades from a website. I used Mechanize to log into the page and navigate to the area I'm scraping. Unfortunately, the page uses Javascript to encrypt the page (possibly to stop me from scraping). I found the decryption script and ported to Python. It works and I used it to extract the encrypted string from the page and when I convert it, it becomes a table in HTML.

So, to get to my point, is there any way to inject the HTML back into the page and use mechanize to use the links on the table to get my grades?

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: I have beautiful soup also, if that is any help.

Comment: You want to inject some code into an external website?

Comment: just use selenium, it's way simpler.

Comment: @feeela No, I want to inject the temporarily locally (I think) to the original page and navigate around it using mechanize. Or find a way to navigate around the HTML string itself somehow using mechanize.

Comment: @root If I am not mistaken, I think that selenium actually opens up a actual browser and you can see the bot navigating around the page? I want to make the code run in the background and work on nearly any computer.

Comment: well it's possible to use selenium with virtual display if you don't want to see it moving around.

Comment: @root Does selenium support webscraping?

Comment: why don't you extract the links directly from decrypted html using beautifulsoup?

Comment: @Peb Is it possible to open an HTML string with Beautiful Soup?

Comment: @EpicDavi That's pretty much what it's designed for. So your aim here is to parse some HTML to find your marks, but in order to do that, you have to insert some html before the original html becomes readable?

Comment: @TankorSmash Thanks, the HTML is just to display a table and it looks like it can work on its own. I researched it and I think I know what to do now.

Comment: @EpicDavi It'd be helpful if you answered your own question below, so others could see what you did to solve your question. Glad you sorted it out though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using this:

```
response = br.open("www.linknotonpagethatiwanttogoto.com")
page = response.read()
```

I found out that you store the .open() of a link as a response, instead of using the .follow_link(). Also the browser uses the same cookies so the session cookies are preserved. So after parsing the html, I popped the links into the .open() and got the new page.